# DELPHI FIREDAC Precedence between master detail relation and calculated fields

Tags: delphi-xe, master-detail, firedac, calculated-field, command-precedence

I have a TFDQuery, I'll call it FDQ_Master, containing a formula in text.  The Idea would be to add a calculated (Or internal calc *same result so far*) field to this FDQ_Master to evaluate this formula.  I have a function using TEvaluator (JclExprEval from Jedi Project) that works just fine when executing from a button click to evaluate the formula.

This function to evaluate requires information from other table (FDQ_Detail) that is a detail table in the defined master detail relation with FDQ_Master.  The FDQ_Master is working on "Cached Updates" which I mention just in case it could have any importance on this concern.  (FDQ_Detail is not updated at all in this form)

The problem I find is that when the OnCalcFields event occurs in the FDQ_Master, FDQ_Detail hasn't yet navigated (Or better say filtered I guess) to the records corresponding to the new master, and so on, the calculation occurs with the wrong set of detail records.

So.  I say, no problem, I add a new TFDQuery to the same table of FDQ_Master, (FDQ_Master_BIS), and I do set a master detail relationship from FDQ_Master_BIS to FDQ_Master (Relation will be 1 to 1) and I try doing the calculations there, but I find the same problem.  And that complicates the matter a bit, because if I do on another detail TFDQuery *Detail from FDQ_Master* it does work (It doesn't make much sense to take this as a solution to the problem as for these detail TFDQueries the calculation would be executed as many times as detail records existed and I need it executed just once for every FDQ_Master records)

And that is my question.  For the first approach (Adding a calculated field to FDQ_Master) Is there any way to prevent the calculation of fields in FDQ_Master till the FDQ_Detail has performed the master-detail relation?

And in case this would not be possible *Or it would just get too complicated* Is there any way to indicate Delphi - Firedac to retrieve records from one TFDQuery before another among different master detail relationships to the same master table?

Of course I could workout a "manual" solution to calculate the formula separately and find a way to put it on the screen, the code would not look so fine, but that solution I guess could be implemented somehow.  The question is more concerning to the precedence of these operations and if is there any way to programatically affect this precedence.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the solution that I did actually implement was the same that I pretended with this FDQ_Master_BIS but the other way around, meaning, Instead of creating FDQ_Master_BIS as detail record from FDQ_Master, I created FDQ_Master_BIS as Master from FDQ_Master and changed the master detail relation in FDQ_Detail to FDQ_Master_BIS instead of FDQ_Master.  I do the calculations in FDQ_Master and so far, seems to work just fine.

Well the actual trick is that FDQ_Master_BIS is selected before opening FDQ_Detail, and so I make sure that when FDQ_Detail is opened is already pointing to the right records.